# how can I define a combinational user define primitive (UDP) with more than one output?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

Is it possible to define a UDP with more than one output? I even try to make bundle output as follow, but it makes some errors.
I'm trying to write the code for an 8-bit prefix adder, and I want to define the operation as a UDP to calculate the value for G and P.
 This is the code:

```
primitive preaddprimitive(pgout,p2,p1,g2,g1);
input p2,p1,g2,g1;
output pgout;
table
// p2 p1 g2 g1 : {pout,gout}
  0 ? 0 ? : 00;
  ? 0 1 ? : 01;
  0 ? 1 ? : 01;
  1 0 0 0 : 00;
  1 0 0 1 : 01;
  1 1 0 0 : 10;
  1 1 0 1 : 11;
  1 1 1 ? : 11;
endtable
endprimitive
```

and this is the error message:

> near "0": syntax error, unexpected '0', expecting ';'

I tried to define to output, but it made the same error.
I tested the code on modelsim 10.c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to define a UDP with more than one output.  According to the IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 29.2 *Overview*:

```
Each UDP has exactly one output, which can be in one of three states: 0, 1, or x.
```

and section 29.3.1 *UDP header*

```
All ports of a UDP shall be scalar; vector ports are not permitted.
```

You can use a `module` instead of a `primitive`.